# How can I prevent page reloads upon saving changes with the Live Server extension for VS Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I'm editing a website using Visual Studio Code with Live Server Plugin.

My HTML contains videos and many lines of text. (education related)
If I edit a line in the middle of the code and save it, it will reload the website.
And I have to go through the videos and other things at the start so then I can get back to the part that I edited.
Can anybody help me prevent the plugin from reloading the web?

I tried with loading the website from ISS (Internet Management Services) and I can edit the file and the web won't be reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of [this GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/256#issuecomment-524521726), put `"liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles":["**"]` in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) (either the user or workspace one- up to you). You may need to stop and restart the live server if it was already running while you changed the settings.